# Xamarin Forms Tab Title Not Changing

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, tabs, tabbedpage

I am trying to change the title of the tab in a tabbed page if the language is changed. I am calling onAppearing() to make sure that if the language is changed the label will be translated. But for some reason the title of the tab is not changing until I refresh the page(closing the app then opening it or signing out then signing in) although the title of the tabbed page is being translated directly.
`Method to translate labels`

```
        private void InitLabels()
    {
        Title = Methods.GetMessage("home");
        ordersPage.Title = Methods.GetMessage("orders");

        // change to RTL if locale is arabic
        if (Methods.InitLocale().Equals("ar"))
            Methods.SetFlowDirection(this, FlowDirection.RightToLeft);
    }


    protected override void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();
        // to be able to update labels if the language is changed
        InitLabels();
    }
```

**Title** is changing but **ordersPage.Title** is not.

Comment: why did you accept the answer on your previous question if it did not actually solve your problem?

Comment: @Jason because it taught me a new concept and solved 50% of the problem. The label is translated but only if I close the app then open it and before that answer I did not know how to access a tab title since I thought it has a different approach.

Comment: @Sam How do you change language? just change language by Device setting? Or other ways?

Comment: @CherryBu-MSFT I created 2 classes both contians dictionary, and I saved the locale inside app property and depending on the locale saved I either go to the MessagesEN(which contains english words) or MessagesAR(which contains arabic words). this logic works perfectly but except for the titles of the tabs I have to close the app then open it again for them to be translated

Comment: @Sam Maybe you can provide one simple sample at github, I will download your sample to test.

Comment: @CherryBu-MSFT when I have time I'll do it, thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

I was able to modify the Xamarin tabs sample to do this

```
// this is a TabbedPage, and it's children are ContentPages
this.Children[0].Title = "shazbat!";
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to refresh the page for the changes to take effect, I used the below code:

```
var vUpdatedPage = new PageToRefresh();
Navigation.InsertPageBefore(vUpdatedPage, this);
await Navigation.PopAsync();
```